# serially subtract from vector elements

Tags: r

I need to subtract a number from a vector in such a way that it is subtracted serially from the elements.  As an example, consider the vector `a = c(8, 4)`. If I want to serially subtract 9 from this vector, I first subtract 9 from the first vector element, 8. That leaves 0 for the first element with a reminder of 1, that then gets subtracted from the second element. That leaves 4-1=3 for the second vector element.

I can do this with a bunch of inelegant if-else statement.  There must be a better way.  It would be easier to show examples:

I assume that the serial subtraction function is called serialSub.

```
a = c(8,4)
serialSub(a,4)
> [1] 4 4

serialSub(a,8)
> [1] 0 4

serialSub(a,9)
> [1] 0 3

serialSub(a,13)
> [1] 0 0

serialSub(a,0)
> [1] 8 4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `tosub` is the total amount to subtract away, then `pmin(cumsum(a), tosub)` is the total amount that should be removed from each element of the cumulative sum of `a`, and therefore `cumsum(a) - pmin(cumsum(a), tosub)` is the cumulative sum of our new vector. We need to obtain the vector that gives this cumulative sum, which can be done using `diff`:

```
a <- c(8, 4)
serialSub <- function(a, tosub) diff(c(0, cumsum(a) - pmin(cumsum(a), tosub)))
serialSub(a,4)
# [1] 4 4
serialSub(a,8)
# [1] 0 4
serialSub(a,9)
# [1] 0 3
serialSub(a,13)
# [1] 0 0
serialSub(a,0)
# [1] 8 4
```

Comment: Or `pmin(pmax(0, cumsum(a) - v), a)`, I think.

Comment: @Frank nice one -- `pmax(0, cumsum(a) - v)` also works for the desired cumulative sum of the resulting vector, and I like the observation that we can just use `pmin` between that and `a` to determine what to keep instead of using `diff`.